# How to connect 2 Arduino Unos when one has a TFT LCD display attached to it?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, tft

I have to make a school project involving an Arduino Uno with a 2.8" TFT LCD touch screen display. in my project, i have to connect it such that the display is linked to a LED push button that receive inputs and react accordingly, as well as a speaker. However, my TFT LCD display fits perfectly into my Arduino Uno meaning i have no more input slots to connect to my push buttons nor my speaker. initially i found a different TFT display that came with an Arduino Shield that made life simplier however those products were not being shipped to my country:(

i am unable to use an Arduino Mega either since the SD socker in my TFT LCD display does not support the Arduino Mega. i understand in order to have my tft lcd display and my LED buttons and speaker to work i can have 2 Arduino Unos and have them work in Master-Slave however i would still need to have a common ground for both arduinos first and connect them which i am unable to do so since there's simply no way i can fit a jumper cable in there once i place my tft lcd display on the arduino uno. Please help guys:(

Comment: Please add a link or additional information about the LCD touch screen shield you are using. There might be pins that are not used by the shield and that may be accesses through jumpers, etc.

Comment: If your TFT shield does not expose unused pins and general pins like 5V, Ground, etc, you have to expose them yourself. You can solder directly to the board, but the cleanest way would be to use another layer (for example a prototyping shield) between Arduino and TFT shield. Some of them have the pins in such a configuration, that you can simply stack the TFT shield on top of it (e.g. it exposes all the pins to further shields, that might be stacked on the prototyping shield).

Comment: this is my LCD touch screen! https://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=2756

Comment: i am hesitant about getting a protoshield as i understand you have to soldering alrdy and then configure it? please correct me if i am wrong!!

Comment: The screw shield I mention in my answer requires no soldering. Just a small screwdriver to tighten the screws to hold your wires that go to the other board.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a screw shield between the TFT shield and the Arduino to make access to the unused pins easier.  You can see an example of a board I offer at www.crossroadsfencing.com/BobuinoRev17/ We have been able to ship to any country to date.

[image]

Comment: This answer is spam, an advertisement for a product. @CrossRoads please read: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: How else is one to post a picture of a suggested solution?  "Don't tell - show! The best way to avoid being seen as a snake-oil salesman is to demonstrate a solution rather than simply asserting the problem can be solved"  "Always solve the asker's problem. A good answer should at minimum allow the person whose question you're answering to solve their problem."

Comment: The relevant thing from that link is: "*you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.*".

Comment: This is not spam. If you have a product that is a solution to the OPs problem there is nothing wrong with suggesting it (provided you disclose your affiliation). I do it often :P Spam is where you try and suggest that Viagra is the solution to the OP's question (which it may be, but that's another issue entirely...) or where you intentionally make it look like you're suggesting someone else's product.

Comment: It was spam until the answer was edited and changed to disclose CrossRoad's affiliation with the product for sale.